# Java: How can I update a variable used in Runnable lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, scheduledexecutorservice

I have the following code. I'm using a `ScheduledExecuterService` in my `scheduleNumbers()` method to display a series of random numbers for a specified amount of milliseconds. However, I can't seem to update the `curNumber` being displayed in the `setNumber` lambda as "local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final" (Very informative). Is there any way to go about this without using threads? Full code is in a pastebin link below.

```
private void printNumbers(int[] randomNumbers) {
    int speed = DIFF_TIMES[difficulty.getSelectedIndex()];
    int amount = BASE_AMOUNT + currentScore;
    answerField.setEditable(false);
    scheduleNumbers(randomNumbers, speed, amount);
    currentNumberLab.setText("");
    answerField.setEditable(true);
}

public void scheduleNumbers(int[] randomNumbers, int speed, int amount) {
    int curNumber = 0;
    long initialDelay = 1000;
    final Runnable setNumber = () -> {
        currentNumberLab.setText(Integer.toString(randomNumbers[curNumber]));
        System.out.println("Set to " + randomNumbers[curNumber]);
    };
    final ScheduledFuture<?> setNumberHandle = scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(setNumber, initialDelay, speed, MILLISECONDS);
    scheduler.schedule(() -> {
        setNumberHandle.cancel(true);
    }, (speed*amount)+initialDelay, MILLISECONDS);
}
```

[Full code](http://pastebin.com/pEsT8ag3).

Edit for clarity:

I'd like to be able to increment `curNumber` so each time `setNumber` is run, it sets `currentNumberLab` to `Integer.toString(randomNumbers[curNumber++])`.

Comment: Holy code dump Batman. Consider learning what SSCCE stand for.

Comment: You have two lambdas in `scheduleNumbers`.  Which one is causing the problem?

Comment: @ajb Updated the question. `setNumber` is causing the problem. I want `curNumber` to be incremented each time it's run so each index of `randomNumbers` is displayed.

Comment: Ah, ha, so you left out the line that increments `curNumber`.  That seems to have confused some answerers.  Next question: when you increment `curNumber`, do you want it to affect the `Runnable`, or do you want the `Runnable` to keep using the `curNumber` value that was in effect when the `Runnable` was created?

Comment: Sorry, but I think it's too hard to figure out what you're trying to do.  Please post the code you would *like* to be able to write even if it isn't legal, and then I think we can tell what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @ajb Ah, my bad. I didn't think to leave it in. I want the `Runnable` to use the new incremented `curNumber` each time. I'll update it now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well actually it is informative...

try the following:

```
public void scheduleNumbers(int[] randomNumbers, int speed, int amount) {
final int curNumber = 0;
```

It needs to be final because once the method is finished you would loose reference of your local variables inside your thread. The method would be finished but the thread might still be running. Declaring a local variable final helps you to get around this issue.

If you would like to update curNumber in the thread use AtomicInteger instead:

```
public void scheduleNumbers(int[] randomNumbers, int speed, int amount) {
final AtomicInteger curNumber = new AtomicInteger();
long initialDelay = 1000;
final Runnable setNumber = () -> {

    currentNumberLab.setText(Integer.toString(randomNumbers[curNumber.incrementAndGet()]));
    System.out.println("Set to " + randomNumbers[curNumber.get()]);
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the problem.  The questioner wants to be able to modify `curNumber`.